# create an instance of a model by clicking a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance

I am pretty new to Ruby and I am working on a hangman game .

What I am trying to do is create a new game when the user simply click on a button and I want that "click" to redirect to the show of that game.

Here are my models :

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :guesses

end
```

```
class Guess < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Here are my controllers :

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    @game.save!
    redirect_to game_path(@game)
  end

  def show
    @game = Game.new
    @game = Game.last
  end

  def destroy
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.destroy
    redirect_to home_path
  end

  private

  words =[
    "spokesperson", "firefighter", "headquarters", "confession", "difficulty", "attachment", "mechanical",
    "accumulation", "hypothesis", "systematic", "attraction", "distribute", "dependence", "environment",
    "jurisdiction", "demonstrator", "constitution", "constraint", "consumption", "presidency", "incredible",
    "miscarriage", "foundation", "photography", "constituency", "experienced", "background", "obligation",
    "diplomatic", "discrimination", "entertainment", "grandmother", "girlfriend", "conversation", "convulsion",
    "constellation", "leadership", "insistence", "projection", "transparent", "researcher", "reasonable","continental",
    "excavation", "opposition", "interactive", "pedestrian", "announcement", "charismatic", "strikebreaker",
    "resolution", "professional", "commemorate", "disability", "collection", "cooperation", "embarrassment",
    "contradiction", "unpleasant", "retirement", "conscience", "satisfaction", "acquaintance", "expression",
    "difference", "unfortunate", "accountant", "information", "fastidious", "conglomerate", "shareholder",
    "accessible", "advertising", "battlefield", "laboratory", "manufacturer", "acquisition", "operational",
    "expenditure", "fashionable", "allocation", "complication", "censorship", "population", "withdrawal",
    "sensitivity", "exaggerate", "transmission", "philosophy", "memorandum", "superintendent", "responsibility",
    "extraterrestrial", "hypothesize", "ghostwriter", "representative", "rehabilitation", "disappointment",
    "understanding", "supplementary", "preoccupation"
 ]

  @word_to_guess = words.sample
  @health_bar = 5
  @game_status = "Game not started yet"

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(@word_to_guess, @health_bar, @game_status)
  end

end
```

Here is what I have been trying to do

```
<%= link_to "nouvelle partie", game_path(game), method: :create %>
```

but the errors message is :
"undefined local variable or method `game' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000000d4d0"

Answer (score 0):

POST method won't work with link_to. Try using the to `button_to` instead of `link_to` like this:

```
<%= button_to "nouvelle partie", game_path(game), method: :post %>
```

I think the bug is due to the variable game not being passed to partial. You have to pass it on like this:

```
<%= render "game", game: @game %>
```

And you don't have to pass variables in `game_params`. You only need to set them in the `show` method where you will be redirected from the `create` method. Also, you don't set the current game like this `Game.last`, you just take `id` which is contained in the url.

```
def create
  @game = Game.new
  @game.save!
  redirect_to game_path(@game)
end

def show
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @word_to_guess = words.sample
  @health_bar = 5
  @game_status = "Game not started yet"
end
```

Comment: Ok Thank you for the ````button_to```` ! But now it's saying "No route matches [POST] "/"
"I don't understand where I should put the ````<%= render "game", game: @game %>````

Comment: `<%= render "game", game: @game%>` is probably in `app/views/games/index.html`

Comment: I don't know the whole idea of your version of the game and I haven't seen all the code and I'm trying to help just by guessing from common bugs.

Comment: That doesn't works. Message error is "No route matches [POST] '/' " and the instance is not created

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
<%= link_to "nouvelle partie", game_path(@game), method: :create %>
```